# crouches and bends down

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-meaning

[crouches and bends down](http://www.biblestudytools.com/csb/psalms/passage.aspx?q=psalms%2010:10-18)

I see in dictionary that crouches means "To stoop, especially with the knees bent", and stoop means "bend forward". Now my question is crouches already means **bend down** with knees bent, so why there the sentence also has "and bends downs" following crouches? Isn't it an unnecessary duplicate?

I think crouches means changing from standing position to the below image. Correct me if I'm wrong.

[image]

Is there any different word to mean same what crouches means but it also mean how fast or how aggressively one crouches. I looking for a word which mean "crouches down very fast"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crouching is different from "bending down." The picture that you have provided is of someone crouching, with his center of gravity in the same vertical plane as it would be were he standing. A person who is bending down would bend be leaning forward with his center of gravity ahead of where it would be were he standing.

To "duck" might imprecisely mean to crouch very quickly, but it could also mean to bend over very quickly or to fall to the ground quickly.

Answer (score 1):

To *crouch and bend down* strikes me as slightly odd phrasing. Perhaps the [Alexandrian Greek Text](http://www.sermonindex.net/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=6028&forum=35&9) (from which OP's [Holman Christian Standard Bible translation](http://www.biblestudytools.com/csb/psalms/passage.aspx?q=psalms%2010:10-18) derives) includes two different verbs meaning *to bend the knees (crouch)* and *to bend the back and/or neck (bow)*.

If OP seeks an expression meaning to adopt such a posture *quickly*, I suggest...

> [[He] **dropped to his haunches**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dropped%20to%20his%20haunches%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (17,900 instances in Google Books)

Note that [[He] dropped to his knees](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22dropped%20to%20his%20haunches%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22dropped%20to%20his%20knees%22&oq=%22dropped%20to%20his%20knees%22&gs_l=serp.3...739035.741633.1.741864.13.13.0.0.0.0.124.770.12j1.13.0...0.0...1c.1.12.serp._GFwFu4A3BY&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.d2k&fp=6ce1b7b82d666dd9&biw=1517&bih=894) is far more common (727,000 hits in GB). But that would normally be understood as meaning *his knees touched the ground*, so if OP wants to accurately describe the exact posture, it's probably not the best choice.

---

Per Daniel's comment below, *drop to your haunches* isn't particularly common in informal speech, where you're more likely to hear...

> [[He quickly] **hunkered down**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22crouched%20and%20bent%20down%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22hunkered%20down%22&oq=%22hunkered%20down%22&gs_l=serp.3...560170.561488.2.561791.8.8.0.0.0.0.63.326.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.12.serp.L6CZe47VBjw&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.d2k&fp=6ce1b7b82d666dd9&biw=1547&bih=894) (144,000 written instances)

OED defines *to hunker* as...

> To squat, with the haunches, knees, and ankles acutely bent, so as to bring the hams near the heels, and throw the whole weight upon the fore part of the feet.

...where it's worth noting firstly that 10 of their 12 citations are for *hunker **down***, and secondly that OED's "draft additions, 1993" includes this definition for the common modern "figurative usage"...

> *With **down.*** To concentrate one's resources, esp. in unfavourable circumstances; to dig in, buckle down; spec. *(freq. in military contexts)* to shelter or take cover, lie low. *orig. and chiefly U.S.*

Comment: Do people actually say "dropped to his haunches"? I've read it in books, but never heard anybody say it.

Comment: @Daniel: Good point. It certainly *does* occur quite often in books, as my GB link shows. And for some reason I assumed OP wanted a (relatively "formal") expression suitable for written contexts. I'll edit the answer to add "hunker down", which I think is far more likely to be used in spoken contexts.

Comment: I have never heard the phrase "hunker down" used that way. I have always heard it used like "He just needs to hunker down and get his work done," implying that someone would be staying in the same place for a long period of time doing something intensely.

Comment: @Daniel: It would be far too difficult for me to establish whether and when that "figurative use" completely eclipsed the literal sense in the US, but I must say it sounds a little unlikely. Are you saying you are/were actually *unaware* of the literal meaning of "to hunker"? On reflection, I do agree with OED that the figurative usage does sound somewhat "American" to me - personally, as a Brit I think I'd be more likely to say ***knuckle** down* (which has no real "literal meaning" to me in any non-contrived context! :).

Comment: I was unaware until I looked it up on Google just now.

Comment: I have heard the phrase "knuckle down" before, but I would never use it as an American. I would always say "hunker down," and I was completely unaware that there was a literal meaning of that expression.

Comment: @Daniel: I'd have thought most instances of [hunkered down behind](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hunkered+down+behind&year_start=1950&year_end=1980&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) on the NGrams American corpus there are effectively "literal", but I suppose if you started from the assumption it meant something like *"keep your nose to the grindstone and get on with whatever it is you need to do"*, you could often read it that way.

Comment: It could certainly be that most of the examples in literature are literal. I would just never use it that way in speech.

Comment: @Daniel: I imagine *knuckle down* is never "literal", and very likely most instances of *hunker down* are figurative on both sides of the pond. Interestingly, prevalence for the former has remained steady, and about equal in both NGrams corpuses, but [US hunker down](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knuckle+down%2Chunker+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) has shot up in the past few decades, [far more than in the UK](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=knuckle+down%2Chunker+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=)